# Angular2 : trouble in integrating ng2-material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to integrating ng2-material in Angular2

> Uncaught SyntaxError:   angular2-polyfills.js:138 Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Evaluating
>   http://localhost:3000/ng2-material/all

```
import {MATERIAL_PROVIDERS, MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-material/all';

   @Component({

       template: `<md-content>
                 <button md-raised-button class="md-raised md-primary">Primary</button>
                 </md-content>`,
       styles: [style],
       providers:[ContactService, MATERIAL_PROVIDERS]
       directives:[MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES]
    })

 export class contact {
    constructor(){}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is my config. It worked. You can try it.

```
System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-material': {
          defaultExtension: 'js'
       }
    },
    map: {
        'ng2-material': 'node_modules/ng2-material'
  },
});
System.import('app/main')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **angular2-beta12** and **ng2-material 0.3.4**

I was having issues getting ng2-material to work as well.

The first thing i was missing in my index.html file was declaring the css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ng2-material/dist/ng2-material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ng2-material/dist/font.css">
```

After that one of the important things I found I was missing was the map information was nested inside the packages bracket.  Once I moved it outside my System.config statement looks like this:

**Index.html**

```
System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng2-material': {//this needs to be nested in packages
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        map: {//The map location needs to be located outside of the package bracket
            'ng2-material': 'node_modules/ng2-material'
        }


    });

    System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Then in my main.ts file I import MATERIAL_PROVIDERS

**Main.ts**

```
import {MATERIAL_PROVIDERS} from "ng2-material/all";
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'


bootstrap(AppComponent, [MATERIAL_PROVIDERS]);
```

Lastly on the component that want to use the ng2-material on I imported MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES

**create.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';
import {MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES} from "ng2-material/all";



@Component({
   templateUrl: 'app/templates/create.html',
   directives: [RouterOutlet, MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES]

})
export class CreateComponent {...component code}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it can't find the library for you, try to `npm install` it again.

Otherwise, if you're certain that you have installed the library is downloaded, add this to your `index.html`:

```
<script>
    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        packages: {
            "/angular2": {"defaultExtension": false}
        },
        map: {
            'ng2material': 'node_modules/ng2material'
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: System.config({
  packages: {app: {format: 'register',defaultExtension: 'js'}}
  
  });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));

how can load app/boot file ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could try this configuration into your HTML file:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-material': {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      'ng2-material': 'node_modules/ng2-material/source'
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: i tried your code but generate error is  like
Unable to load script http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-material/source/all.js(…)

Comment: map: {
      'ng2-material': 'node_modules/ng2-material/source'
    }

i use 
 map: {
      'ng2-material': 'node_modules/ng2-material'
    }
then it give me this error
ReferenceError: require is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I am using:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>
  System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
</script>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ng2-material/dist/ng2-material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ng2-material/dist/font.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      'ng2-material': 'node_modules/ng2-material/source'
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

As noted in the comment above, including the package entry for ng2-material gives a require not defined error.  I don't know if the placement of the setting of defaultJSExtensions is critical, but it must be done and doing things in this order works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 
import {MATERIAL_PROVIDERS} from "ng2-material";

remove "/all"